# REST service: Get Request to a URL with a special string parameter

Tags: c#, rest

I wrote a simple REST Collection WCF service with REST Start Kit Preview 2. The template project provides a Service class with a Dictionary collection instance as its internal collection items. Each item has a key and a value.

The problem is that if the key contains a '.' such as 'ProductA.Item1', then my query to a specific item will not work. The url GET request to this item is something like:

```
  http://localhost:1247/Service.svc/ProductA.Item1
```

It looks like that IIS treats the URL as a resource instead of passing xxx.xxx as a parameter to my REST service's OnGetItem(string id) method. If I remove the part of '.Item1' (building the internal collection with none-dot-like keys such as 'ProductAItem1'), it works fine.

I even tried to change me WebGet attribute's UriTemplate to Products({id}), and then tried this customized URL:

```
  http://localhost:1247/Service.svc/Products(ProductA.Item1)
  http://localhost:1247/Service.svc/Products('ProductA.Item1')
```

Still I cannot reach to my code OnGetItem(string id) method. Without dot-like keys, the customized URL works fine as well.

I am not sure that dot or '.' in URL is a special character by IIS server or not. How can I escape it or make it like string parameter with dot inside if it is special char? Or I just cannot use the dot in my URL at all?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is caused by the way the classes in System.Web.Routing work.  Apparently this used to be a problem for the ASP.NET MVC guys ([see blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx)) but according to that post by Phil Haack, the problem is supposed to be fixed.  Maybe the REST starter kit does not use the new Routing dll yet?

Comment: That's very possible. The routing service might block the call to OnGetItem(). I'll double-check in ASP.Net Forum. Thanks!